# How to controll admin reducer in admin-on-rest?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm sorry if i missing this part in document.

Is there any way i can dispatch an action to manipulate the `admin reducer` ?

### Use Case

I tried to create a custom edit and take a response from server to update an entity on `redux-store` without press a refresh button every single time

### Update:

i use a dialog for some actions, after click edit button in `<List>` the dialog will be appeared, what i tried to do is dispatch the actions to update the record in `redux-store` after api response

```
const enhance = compose(
  withHandlers({
    onExit: ({ onClose }) => () => {
      onClose('addSection');
    },
  }),
  withHandlers({
    onSave: ({ onExit, id }) => values => {
      restClient(CREATE, 'sections', {
        data: {
          name: values.name,
          content: values.content,
          status: true,
          survey_id: id,
        },
      }).then(() => onExit());
    },
  }),
  branch(props => !props.isOpen, renderNothing),
);

const EditQuestionDialog = enhance(
  ({ isOpen, onExit, onSave, onChange, data }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog open={isOpen} onRequestClose={onExit} modal>
          <SimpleForm save={onSave} redirect="list">
            <TextInput source="name" />
            <TextInput source="content" />
          </SimpleForm>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Can you share the custom `Edit` component code ?

Comment: @Gildas: i updated the question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then check the source of the [`Edit`](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/mui/detail/Edit.js) component.

In a nutshell, you should avoid calling the restClient directly. In your enhance method, use redux `connect` to bind the `crudCreate` action and call it in your `onSave` handler.

That way, you will leverage the existing saga which will take care of updating the store for you.

Comment: thanks, it works, but after success it redirects to an undefined pathname. I did change `redirect` prop of `SimpleForm` to `false`

Comment: The `crudCreate` action take a `redirectTo` as its last parameter. See https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/actions/dataActions.js#L44